# AKS | How to integrate VerticalPodAutoscaler

Tags: azure-aks

I am trying to implement an example application for VerticalPodAutoscaler (VPA) and got this error

`error: unable to recognize "foo.yaml": no matches for kind "VerticalPodAutoscaler" in version "autoscaling.k8s.io/v1beta2"`

---

Source code refered: https://medium.com/infrastructure-adventures/vertical-pod-autoscaler-deep-dive-limitations-and-real-world-examples-9195f8422724

```
apiVersion: autoscaling.k8s.io/v1
kind: VerticalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: bar
spec:
  targetRef:
    apiVersion: "apps/v1"
    kind:       Deployment
    name:       foo
  updatePolicy:
    updateMode: "Off"
```

I also tried combinations of v1, vXbetaY but nothing was working.

**Debugging Done**:

1. I tried to search specific examples for Azure AKS VPA but did not find any relevant documentation.
2. I did this `kubectl api-resources | grep autoscaling` and ONLY HorizontalPodAutoscaler is present in this list

Any thing that I am missing for getting VPA working on AKS?

Comment: AKS doesn't have it by default. Also I personally dont use it in AKS as Horizontal Pod Autoscaler and Cluster Autoscaler(for increasing nodes) does all the tricks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, since its a custom resource, you first need to install it. https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler#installation